# How can I set the RGB Color in font Using xssfworkbook npoi

Tags: c#, colors, background, rgb, npoi

How can I set the RGB color in `cell backgroudn` using class `xssfworkbook` using npoi?

```
byte[] rgb = new byte[3] { 192, 50, 90 };
XSSFCellStyle HeaderCellStyle1 = (XSSFCellStyle)wb.CreateCellStyle();
HeaderCellStyle1.SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 255)));
```

I don't want to use this pattern:

```
titlestyle.BottomBorderColor = IndexedColors.Grey25Percent.Index;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    solution of your problem is here
    
    here simply define new xssfcolor and assign it to xssfcellstyle     
    
    
 var color = new XSSFColor(new byte[] { 0,255, 0 });
 var rowstyle =(XSSFCellStyle)wb.CreateCellStyle();
 rowstyle.SetFillForegroundColor(color)
```

Comment: I had to add one more line to get this working in .Net Core 3.1:
    
    rowStyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure you cast your font to `XSSFFont` first, IFont does not offer access to the RGB color properties of the font.

You can then set the color using an `XSSColor`, which can either be constructed from a byte array or a System.Drawing.Color object.

Example code, different varieties of the constructor in comments:

```
var wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");

// Create a colored font
var font = (XSSFFont) wb.CreateFont();
// var color = new XSSFColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C88C14"));
// var color = new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
var color = new XSSFColor(new byte[] {200, 140, 20});
font.SetColor(color);

// Create a dedicated cell style using that font 
var style = wb.CreateCellStyle();
style.SetFont(font);

// Create some cell values
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Standard text");
var cell = row.CreateCell(1);
cell.SetCellValue("Colored text");

// Apply the cellstyle we created
cell.CellStyle = style;
```

Comment: Paul, Doesn't this change the font color?  PParmar's original question asked how to change the cell background/foreground color.

Comment: @AmosLong If you check the question history, you'll find the -original- question asked specifically about the font color :-). The question was modified after I answered it,  making this answer kind of obsolete. I'm leaving it up because some people seem to find it useful.